# Boolean algebra simplification to lowest form

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am relearning Boolean algebra for a class, but I cant seem to simplify this expression any further. It is possible that its fully simplified but I wanted a second opinion.

the expression:

```
(!a*!b*!c)+(!c*(b*a))+(!a*(c*b)) where * is and ; + is or
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
(!a * !b * !c) == !(a + b + c)
```

Second:

```
(!c * (b * a)) == (!c * b * a)
```

Now the second and third ORed sections can be simplified to:

```
b * a ^ c
```

Where ^ is an XOR (exclusive OR: either a or c, but not both). If you take the order of precedence of operators into account, you may be able to discard even more parentheses, but to play it safe:

```
!(a + b + c) || (b * a ^ c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct. Nothing further to reduce to.